# I want to download composer but when I run composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1" it shows this errors

Tags: php, laravel

Changed current directory to /Users/macair/.composer
./composer. json has been updated
Running composer update laravel/installer
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
-laravel/installer v1.1.0 requires symfony/console~2.5 found symfony/console[v2.5.0
V2.8.52] but the package is fixed to v6.0.3 (lock file versi
on) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list lt as an                    argument for the update command,
-laravel/installer\v1.1.1 v1.2.21 reguire SumTony consol Tound symrony/consolelvz.3.0 V2.8.52] but the package is fixed to v6.0.3 (10 ck file version)  by a partial update  and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an   argument for the update command
-laravel/installer[v1.3.0, v1.4.1] require symfony/console found symfony/consolelv2.3.0, v2.8.52, v3.0.0 v3.4.471 but the package is fixed to v6.0.3 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you  list it as an argument for the update command.
-laravel/installer v1.5.0 requires symTonv console ~3.9@4.9 found symfony/console[v3.0.0, V3.44 va.4.371 but the package 1S TiXed to v6.0.3 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make   sure you list it   as an argument for the update command
-Root composer. ison reguires laravelinstaller ~1.1 satisfiable by laravel/installer(v1.1.0,v1.5.0] Use the option

with-all-dependencies(-W) to allow uparades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions

Installation failed reverting composer-sonand/composer.lock to their original content

Comment: Try to update you composer
composer self-update --1

Comment: after running composer delft-update --1-   it shows this, warning: You forced the install of 1.10.25 via --1, but 2.2.6 is the latest stable version. Updating to it via composer self-update --stable is recommended.
Upgrading to version – (1.x channel).

Comment: try composer self-update --stable

Comment: This needs your composer.json file to be easily answered. Also your console output is unreadable (it should be copied and pasted).